# In python datatable not getting right results on filter, groupby, sum chaining

Tags: python, datatable

I am new to **datatable** & trying it in **python** for 1st time.

What I am trying to do is filter condition, then group by ID and then sum on `Count` column on below datatable:

```
import datatable as dt

from datatable import (dt, f, by, ifelse, update, sort,
                       count, min, max, mean, sum, rowsum)

df = dt.Frame(""" ID  Num  Letter  Count
                  1   17   D       1
                  1   12   D       2
                  1   13   D       3
                  2   17   D       4
                  2   12   A       5
                  2   16   D       1
                  3   16   D       1""")
```

filtering based on conditions worked:

```
df[((f.Num == 17) | (f.Num == 12) & (f.Letter == 'D')),:]
```

```
ID  Num Letter  Count
▪▪▪▪    ▪▪▪▪    ▪▪▪▪    ▪▪▪▪
0   1   17  D   1
1   1   12  D   2
2   2   17  D   4
```

But when I do all together, filter, group & sum then I don't get any results:

```
df[((f.Num == 17) | (f.Num == 12) & (f.Letter == 'D')),:
  ][:,update(Total = sum(f.Count)), 
   by(f.ID)]
```

**Expected Result (using R dplyr code):**

```
# df here is r data frame
df %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    filter(Num == 17 | Num == 12,
           Letter == "D") %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(Total = sum(Count))
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID Total
  <int> <int>
1     1     3
2     2     4
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
df[((f.Num == 17) | (f.Num == 12) & (f.Letter == 'D')),:
  ][:,{"Total": sum(f.Count)}, 
   by(f.ID)]
```

```
ID  Total
▪▪▪▪    ▪▪▪▪▪▪▪▪
0   1   3
1   2   4
```

use of update() was unnecessary as this is summarizing results !!